# Form Submission does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

My form submission does not work . Nothing happens when i submit the form. I tried everything but no result.
I have looked at everything on here that I can find and I just can't figure out why I cannot perfect this code.

My code

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $('contact_queryf').bind('click', function (event) {

event.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Views/query_send.php',
            data: $('contact_queryf').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });

        });
      });
    </script>
```

my form code

```
<form role="form"  method="post" id="contact_queryf" name="contact_queryf">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">                
        <div class="radio-inline">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="qtype" id="qtype" value="Android" required>Android
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="qtype" id="qtype" value="iOS" required>iOS
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="qtype" id="qtype" value="Web" required>Web
            </label>

            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="qtype" id="qtype" value="other" required>Other
            </label>                                    
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="text" id="text" required></textarea>
     </div>               

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom bleft" id="contact_query" name="contact_query">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing to try:

```
data: $('#contact_queryf').serialize()
```

instead of

```
data: $('contact_queryf').serialize()
```

(you were missing the #)

Also, you want to bind the click event to "#contact_query" (the submit button), not to the form itself, so

```
$('#contact_query').bind(...
```

instead of

```
$('contact_queryf').bind(...
```

Comment: I would also recommend using `.on()`, as well as a recent version of jQuery. It's not his problem, but if you want to "perfect the code"...

Comment: i correct it # but not working .by using firebug i see status 500
Internal Server Error

Comment: A 500 error means there's a problem on the server-side; that is, a problem in your PHP.

Comment: Yea, but why submit the form when a user clicks on the form? If that is the case the user will submit the form when attempting to input data in a textbox. LOL, every character the user types will submit the form.

Comment: Except `contact_queryf` is the entire form. You should change your  answer instead of just suggesting using the submit button id

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $('#contact_queryf').on('click', function (event) {

      event.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Views/query_send.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
          // response
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
      });

    });
  });
```

Take a look on the documentation - [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `<button type="submit"` to submit the form you do not need the AJAX.

Or am I missing something?

Right now you're submitting the form when a user clicks the form.

**Here you go cat daddy**

This can get you jump started in submitting a form via AJAX but at a lower level.

This is really what you're attempting to do.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom bleft" id="contact_query" name="contact_query" onclick="btnSubmitForm(event)">Submit</button>


    var btnSubmitForm = function (event) {

       event.preventDefault();

        var newForm = new FormData(document.forms[0]),
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            that = this;

        xhr.onload = function () { /*do something when response is back from server*/ };
        xhr.open('GET|POST|PUT|DELETE', 'YOUR URL', true);
        xhr.send(newForm);
        return false;
    };
```

Comment: It's true that the OP shouldn't do the Ajax form submission whenever the form itself is clicked, no.  But it's not unreasonable to submit the form via Ajax instead of allowing the normal submission POST to occur. The typical case is where you want to submit a form that is part of a page without reloading the entire page.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the # in your jquery selector

```
$('contact_queryf').bind('click', function (event) {
```

Should be

```
$('#contact_queryf').bind('click', function (event) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The `selector` is incorrect, change the selector's

```
$(function () {
        $('#contact_query').bind('click', function (event) {

event.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Views/query_send.php',
            data: $('#contact_queryf').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });

        });
      });
```

OR

```
$(function () {
        $('#contact_queryf').submit(function (event) {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Views/query_send.php',
            data: $(event.target).serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });
          return false;
        });
      });
```

And in HTML, form close `</form>` tag is missing